# How to load complex xml files containing more than 1 row tag into dataframe using spark scala and save it as table(note generic solution)

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, xpath-2.0

(This is a sample xml file with 2 row tags(any approach to load this to dataframe with n numbers of row tags or elements using xpath in spark scala)

```
<book id="0">
    <author>Matthew</author>
    <publish_date>Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2000</publish_date>
    <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML. 
    </description>
 <price id = "1">   
    <price>44.95</price>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
</price>
</book>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create schema for above xml file as below.

   ```
   val innerSchema = StructType(
   StructField("price",
   ArrayType(
     StructType(
       StructField("price",LongType,true)::
         StructField("genre",StringType,true)::Nil
         StructField("title",StringType,true)::Nil
     )
   ),true)::Nil
   )

   val schema = StructType(
    StructField("author",StringType,true)::
    StructField("publish_date", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("description", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("price", innerSchema, true):: Nil
    )
   ```
2. Apply this schema to read xml file

   ```
    val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
             .option("rowTag", "Item")
             .schema(schema)
             .load(xmlFile)
             //Selecy nested field and explode to get the flattern result
             .select("author", "publish_date", "description","price.*") // select 
                     required column
   ```

   You can let the spark to infer schema itself will get the same result

   ```
   val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
     .option("rowTag", "Item")
    //.schema(schema)
    .load(xmlFile)
    .select("author", "publish_date", "description","price.*") // select required column
   ```
3. Save data to Hive table.

   ```
      df.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("dbName.tableName");
   ```
4. Even you can save DF to Database as below.

   ```
     //create properties object
     val prop = new java.util.Properties
     prop.setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
     prop.setProperty("user", "root")
     prop.setProperty("password", "pw") 

     //jdbc mysql url - destination database is named "data"
     val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data"

     //destination database table 
     val table = "sample_data_table"

     //write data from spark dataframe to database
     df.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, table, prop)
   ```

**Update :**

To save DataFrame as csv

1. You can use databricks spark-csv. 
   https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

   ```
   df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(filepath)
   ```
2. With Spark 2.x the spark-csv package is not needed as it's included in Spark.

   ```
   df.write.format("csv").save(filepath)
   ```

Please refer https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks any idea how to save output as csv in local path as I am facing error like winutils.exe doesn't exist but it do exist in my system.

Comment: I have updated my comment(Save Dataframe as csv). Please check. Please refer  https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html regarding winutils error.